# SDL_ttf TTF_OpenFont returns NULL

Tags: c++

I am having Problem loading SDL_TTF font.
My code:

```
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont( "Arial.ttf", 24 );
std::cout << "ERROR:" << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
SDL_Color color = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };

SDL_Rect Message_Rect = { 400,400,100,100 };
SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Text", color);
SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer, surface);
SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, Message, NULL, &Message_Rect);
```

I copied Arial.ttf in Debug folder. TTF_GetError() returns "library not initialized". I check Linker-Input-additional dependencies. 
It contains

```
SDL2.lib  
SDL2main.lib  
SDL2_image.lib  
SDL2_mixer.lib  
SDL2_ttf.lib
```

SDL version 2.0.5
SDL_image version 2.0.1
SDL_mixer version 2.0.1
SDL_ttf version 2.0.14

I check values in Debug mode. Before TTF_OpenFont 0xcccccccc, after 0x00000000

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you haven't initialised SDL TTF. You can do it like this:

```
if (TTF_Init() < 0) {
    // Error handling code
}
```

Comment: I add this string: std::cout << "TTF_INIT RETURNS: " << TTF_Init() << std::endl; In Console show TTF_INIT RETURNS: 0

Comment: @AceMan Did you add the line before this line: `TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont( "Arial.ttf", 24 );`?